# Proving $lim_{b\to \infty} (1- x/b)^{-b} = e^{x}$

Tags: analysis

I'm reading some footnotes in my textbook, and having a hard time following this logic:

" At large b, we have $1-x/b = e^{-x/b}+O(b^{-b^2})$ implying that $(1-x/b)^{-b} = (e^{-x/b})^{-b}(1+e^{x/b}O(b^{-2}))^{-b}= e^{x}(1+e^{x/b}O(b^{-2}))^{-b}$ "

I understand this, easy to follow. Next we're told:

"Note that $1+e^{x/b}O(b^{-2})$ has the form $e^{y/b^2} + O(b^{-3})$ for some y, and hence $(1+e^{x/b}O(b^{-2}))^{-b}$ = $e^{-y/b}(1 + e^{-y/b^2}O(b^{-3}))^{-b}$ "

This step confuses me, what does it mean for something to "have a form" ?

Finally:

"iterating this we see that all the factors associated with these higher terms become 1 as b is sent to infinity, leaving the result $e^{x}$"

I think this is an interesting trick, and I'd like to understand it. It also was described as a standard result, but could not find it online. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This does get the result, though the specific mechanism used in the text is still confusing to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\left(1-\frac{x}{b}\right)^{-b}= 1-{-b \choose 1} \frac{-x}{b}+ {-b \choose 2} \left(\frac{-x}{b}^2 \right)^2+ {-n \choose 3} \left(\frac{-x}{b}\right)^3+ {-b \choose 4} \left(\frac{-b}{4}\right)^4....$$
$$\left(1-\frac{x}{b}\right)^{-b}=1+x+\frac{b(b+1)}{2!~b^2}x^2+\frac{b(b+1)(b+2)}{3!~ b^3} x^3+\frac{b(b+1)(b+2)(b+3)}{4!~b^4}x^4+...$$
Thus,
$$\lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \left(1-\frac{x}{b}\right)^{-b}=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+....=e^x$$

Comment: Thank you, this is straightforward. Do you understand the argument in the question?

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding my actual question.

Comment: Then you must see several other solutions given by the first comment below your question.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific about my actual question in the title. I'm asking about the specific method used here in my explanation. Your answer is marked.